# JSF rewrite the action parameter in the rendered HTML form

Tags: jsf, nginx, primefaces, wildfly

I have the situation where we will have access to the two JSF aplication on different servers from different url-s from the same domain, for example:

1.) https://domain1.com/portal
2.) https://domain1.com/portal-devel

We have the NGINX proxi in front to do the redirect. The aplication is deployed on Wildfy server in the root context.

So what happens is that the HTML forms rendered by JSF has the action="/login.jsf" so the post here actialy goes to https://domain1.com/login.jsf and of course there is nothing there.

What is the best option here, is it possible to remove the / from the action param in the form generated by JSF? Or is a beter practice that I deploy the aplication actualy in a context-root "/portal"?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use relative path in JSF action. In this case you will stay on the same position/directory in navigation path.

This works with JSF redirect, but I could not say if it works with external redirect automagicaly. Perhaps you will need to investigate header and extract path, as we do in Servlet filter for example.